# Find a better way to generate a map using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this enum:

```
public enum FieldType
{
    INTEGER
    {
        @Override
        Set<Class<?>> getTypes()
        {
            return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(int.class, Integer.class));
        }
    },
    LONG
    {
        @Override
        Set<Class<?>> getTypes()
        {
            return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(long.class, Long.class));
        }
    };
    // More types...

    private static final Map<Class<?>, FieldType> _fieldTypes;

    static
    {
        _fieldTypes = Stream.of(values()).
            flatMap(ft -> ft.getTypes().stream()).
            collect(toMap(t -> t,
                t -> Stream.of(values()).
                filter(ft -> ft.getTypes().contains(t)).
                findAny().
                get()
            ));
    }

    abstract Set<Class<?>> getTypes();

    // More methods...
}
```

As you can see, I have a map inside this enum that maps types to field types. I managed to populate this map in the static block using streams. It works, but I think that maybe there's a better and concise way to do it. I can put the second parameter of the *toMap* method in a new method, but I think I'm just moving the complexity somewhere else.

Do you have a suggestion on how to achieve the same thing in a simple way?

Comment: This is a masterclass in writing code no one will ever understand

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a better way to achieve this.

Comment: The dot at the end tells me that the line is not complete, that there's still something to come. I got this advice from the book 'Code Complete', by Steve McConnell. Besides, to me it's ugly that a line stats with a dot, even thought many people use it.

Comment: @Novaterata "The naming convention would be FIELD_TYPES as it's static and final." Debatable. It is `static final`, but it is not immutable.

Comment: @Marcos I'd say (very) common convention far outweighs advice from a book or personal preference. But that's just my opinion...

Comment: @Marcos I've always used the lack of a `;` or `}` to suggest that the line continues.

Comment: @shmosel Also, it's just my opinion. I think that this issue is just personal taste. I just find the book advice on this very sensible, that's way I adopted it to me.

Comment: @Novaterata There is at least one rather well-known software community that imposes the requirement of immutability in their [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names)

Comment: @Marcos Technically, yes, it's a matter of taste. But if you're ever expecting other people to read or maintain your code, it's usually a good idea to follow accepted conventions.

Comment: As far as it being sensible, you could logically argue the exact opposite: the dot at the beginning tells you it's a continuation of the previous line, and the beginning of the line is what you see first (sometimes it's all you can see). Not to mention that the end of the line speaks for itself by the lack of a semicolon.

Comment: IMO, two nested for loops would be much simpler, more concise (and more efficient, but that doesn't matter much).

Comment: `_fieldTypes = EnumSet.allOf(FieldType.class).stream() 
 .collect(HashMap::new, (m,t) -> t.getTypes().forEach(c->m.put(c,t)), Map::putAll);`

Comment: @Holger Interesting. Do this parallelize well?

Comment: @Marcos: the construct itself works correctly with a parallel stream, but with this small number of `enum` constants, there won’t be any benefit from parallel processing (it’s hard to imagine for a reasonable `enum` type to ever have so many constants that processing them in parallel would make sense) and you are using this construct in a static class initializer, so you should not use a parallel stream there, unless you want to risk deadlocks.

Comment: @Holger I asked not because I intended to parallelize such a code, for the reasons you cited. I just asked because I like to have stream code without side-effect, even though I will never run it in parallel. It's just like a 'good practice' I follow, and because it is recommended.

Comment: @Marcos: I appreciate that. In fact, I’d consider stream code that will break in parallel execution as invalid, as such code would rely an artifacts of sequential execution that aren’t guaranteed. That’s why I took the time to explain that this code is formally correct and would work in a parallel context (outside a class initializer). But I also addressed the performance because “Do this parallelize well?” is an ambiguous question. It does “parallelize well” in the sense of producing correct results, but it doesn’t “parallelize well” in terms of performance benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can box into `Entry`'s while flatmapping:

```
_fieldTypes = Stream.of(values())
    .flatMap(ft -> ft.getTypes().stream() // for every Class<?> of a FieldType...
        .map(cls -> new SimpleEntry<>(cls, ft))) // get Entry<Class<?>, FieldType>
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

---

As bradimus suggested, you can also use `collectingAndThen` and `Collections.unmodifiableMap` to create an unmodifiable map from the result of `toMap`:

```
.collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue),
    Collections::unmodifiableMap));
```

Comment: You might mention `CollectingAndThen` to create an unmodifiable map.

Comment: Sounds good. I only have to create a private SimpleEntry class.

Comment: @Eugene Nice. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Marcos It's in the JDK, you can use: `import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;`

Comment: @bradimus Thanks, I added it.

Comment: Marked as an answer. Thanks. I just think that it can't be made better.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little bit simpler:

```
Map<Class<?>, FieldType> map = Arrays.stream(FieldType.values())
                .flatMap(ft -> ft.getTypes().stream()
                      .map(cl -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(cl, ft)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Obviously you could wrap it into `Collections.unmodifiableMap`